# ¿Cómo puedo usar la función getline con string?

Tags: c++

Quiero guardar un texto de 2 palabras en mi variable `string`, sé que el compilador sólo detectará  después de un espacio.

```
string nombre;

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "; cin>>nombre;
cout<<nombre;
```

Si ingreso Jose Luis, solo me imprimirá Jose

```
char nombre[20];

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "; cin.getline(nombre,20,'\n';
cout<<nombre;
```

Sé que puedo utilizar `char` y la función `cin.getline`
Pero quiero usarlo con **string** y no me va a funcionar esto:

```
string nombre;

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "; cin.getline(nombre,20,'\n');
cout<<nombre;
```

***¿Que es lo que debo hacer para usar string?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás usando es el método [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) de la clase [istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/), donde su primer parámetro es de tipo `char*`, esto quiere decir que solo puede recibir la dirección de una variable que sea de tipo `char`.

**Solución:** Debes usar la función [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
std::string nombre;
std::cout << "Ingrese su nombre: "; 
std::getline(std::cin, nombre);
std::cout << nombre;
```